# Nav Header com login

Tags: android, android-layout

Tenho o menu navigation drawer e na parte do header tenho apenas uma imagem. Gostaria de colocar para o usuário realizar um login. Em miúdos gostaria de deixar como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de colocar a imagem o nome e o e-mail do usuario já feito o login. 
Alguém pode me auxiliar, me falar se é muito dificil ? 
Obrigado.

Eu tenho o código:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="@string/label_header"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Subtitle"
    android:id="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/label_headerSmall"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: Que tal colocar os códigos que já tem, para termos um ponto de partida? Além disso, quando usar uma captura de tela para descrever o problema, tente escrever uma descrição da imagem. A ajuda pode vir de um(a) usuário(a) de leitores de tela. :)

Comment: @PabloAlmeida editei a minha pergunta e coloquei o xml que possuo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fala Artur, beleza ?

Cara, tem um livro muito bom do professor Nelson Glauber, o primeiro Google Developer Expert da América Latina. E nele tem um capítulo que ele trata justamente o que precisa, uma Navigation Drawer com login, no caso com o Google Plus e já puxa a foto do usuário. Abaixo segue o link do livro, caso queira dar uma olhada, e do Github com todos os fontes deste capítulo do livro. Espero ter ajudado. Abraços

[Livro](http://novatec.com.br/livros/dominando-android-2ed/)

[GitHub](https://github.com/nglauber/dominando_android2/tree/master/Cap14/GooglePlus)

Comment: Fala Leonardo. Blz sim cara. Vou comprar este livro para dar mais uma estudada no android. Baixei também o projeto. Valeu ai pela força cara. Abs.

Comment: @ArturMafezzoliJúnior Magina mano, estamos junto! Precisando é só falar, se conseguir solucionar seu problema, marca como sulucionado aí por favor =) E qual das respostas te ajudou a solucionar.

Answer (score 1):

Fala Artur,

É melhor você tratar isso direto no Java, quando o usuário faz o login, você salva ele no banco de dados local, certo?

Antes de setar esse valores de nome e email do usuário logado, você faz um if, exemplo:

```
if(logado){
    nome.setText(nome);
    email.setText(email);
}else{
    nome.setText("Você precisa se logar");
    email.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Abraços.

Comment: Leonardo, entendi o que você quis dizer. Mas o meu problema é que nem a tela de login eu tenho ainda. =(